# Unable to put two AlertControllers on same VC

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift2, uialertcontroller

I have a screen with a collection view of items. If the user has not selected anything, I want an alert to pop up, prompting them to choose something. If they have chosen something, I want an alert to pop up, asking if they are ready to move on? Below is my code for this:

```
   if (isSelected) {
        // create the alert
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Create", message: "Make sure to select at least one item.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: { action in
            alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {

        let alert2 = UIAlertController(title: "Move on", message: "Are you ready to move on?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)


        alert2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { action in
            self.performSegue to next screen
        }))

        n.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: { action in

        }))

    }
```

The code seems to be fine but i get the following error:

```
Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior
```

This seems like it should work pretty easily and a common thing to do, but there is no solution on line to this problem. Any help/guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

you had missed to present the **alert2**

```
 self.presentViewController(alert2, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Add that and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This line is not required:

alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

Also add

```
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

in else part.